# Why does stat fail using a name from readdir?

Tags: c, linux, file, readdir

I wrote a program that print the directory name or file name. It's easy but I got something trouble.
It couldn't distinguish directory and file type. I know and I used stat.st_mode to finish it. But something is wrong:

[image]

When I use gdb to check the st_mode value, I found it was 0, except "." and "..", so here is the question: why st_mode is 0?

and that is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *pDir = opendir("MyDirectory");
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    struct stat vStat;

    if (pDir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the directory \"MyDirectory\"");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(pDirent->d_name, &vStat);
        if (S_ISDIR(vStat.st_mode))
            printf("Directory: %s\n", pDirent->d_name);
        else
            printf("File: %s\n", pDirent->d_name);
    }

    closedir(pDir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, errno == 2 meant No such file or directory

Comment: Don't post screenshots. You are required to post text unless you have a problem with a screenshot itself.

Answer (score 8):

Classic `readdir` mistake: `pDirent->d_name` is the name of the directory entry, not a path to the file. It's `"1"`, `"4-5.c"`, etc. So your `stat` calls are looking for a file with that name *in the current directory*, not under `MyDirectory`.

Check the return value of `stat`. You'll see that it's `ENOENT` — except for `.` and `..`, which exist in the current directory as well. When `stat` fails, the content of the stat structure is undefined.

If you're calling `opendir` in a directory other than `.`, then to do pretty much anything useful with the returned names, you need to build a full path. Copy the path you passed to `opendir` to a buffer with enough room for a slash and file name in addition, and copy each file name to that buffer. Proof-of-concept code (error checking omitted, etc.):

```
char *directory = "MyDirectory";
size_t directory_length = strlen(directory);
char *path = malloc(directory_length + 1 + NAME_MAX);
strcpy(path, directory);
path[directory_length] = '/';
while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
    strcpy(path + directory_length + 1, pDirent->d_name);
    if (stat(path, &vStat) == -1) {
        perror(path);
        continue;
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now I know the reason. Yes, You're right, and it's the best way I think. And I also got the another way, that's use chdir(pathname), and that's also worked.

Comment: @SmithJohn: note that using `chdir()` works, but can leave you with problems if you need to process several directories in one command.  How do you get back to where you started?  (One answer is [`fchdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html)
 — others are considerably more complex.)