# C - stat struct not working properly

Tags: c, file, struct, stat

I am trying to printf some characteristics of the files inside a directory (only the ones that start with lowercase). However, when I execute the following code, **some of them work and some don't**. It looks like the stat struct may not be working properly, but I haven't been able to identify the error so far.

```
struct dirent *ep;
DIR *dp;    
char* cwd;
char buff[PATH_MAX + 1];
off_t tamTotal=0;
struct stat archivo;    
char path[]="/home/edu/Escritorio/P7/practica7/prueba";

if(!(dp=opendir(path))){
    printf("Error.\n");
    exit(-1);
}

printf("\nFILES:\n");
while (ep = readdir (dp)){ 
    stat(ep->d_name, &archivo);
    if(S_ISREG(archivo.st_mode)){
        if(!isupper(ep->d_name[0])){
            printf("  %s\n",ep->d_name);
            printf("    Last modification date: %s \n",ctime(&archivo.st_mtime));
            printf("    i-no number: %lu \n",archivo.st_ino);
            printf("    Blocks: %lu \n",archivo.st_blocks);
            printf("    Size: %lu \n",archivo.st_size);
        }       
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Well you're not checking the return value of `stat`, so how can you know if it's "working correctly" or not? I will never understand why people decide to omit error-checking, and then come to Stack Overflow asking why their code is behaving strangely.

Comment: Perhaps read [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) and check the return value would help

Comment: Indeed, it gives me an error when I create the struct. Any ideas why?

Comment: `if(!S_ISREG(...` means "if this is *not* a regular file".

Comment: Well that's what `errno` would tell you. Please, use `perror`, or `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: It tells me: No such file or directory. But I am pretty sure my path is correct. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `dirent` structure returned by `readdir` only contains the name and not the directory or full path.

As a result, `stat` will fail, which you don't notice because you don't check its return value.

Comment: Yep - exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168266/why-is-stat-not-working-after-readdir