# Not able to visit subfolders recursively

Tags: c, linux, recursion, directory, filesystems

I am trying to build a program that recursively lists all folders and files in a directory, along with their file sizes. I'm still working on the first part because the program only seems to go one level of sub-folder in depth.

Can anyone spot the issue here? I'm stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void listdir(const char *name) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int file_size;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            printf("./%s\n", entry->d_name);
            listdir(entry->d_name);
        }
        else
            printf("./%s\n", entry->d_name);
    } while (readdir(dir) != NULL);
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    listdir(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`). Your fix-my-code question is off-topic, and lacks some other tag (like *linux* or *POSIX*) since standard C does not know about directories (but POSIX does).

Comment: Reporting an error instead of simply returning might be a good idea ...

Comment: `char *path[1024]` allocates an array of `char` pointers, which is probably not what you want...

Comment: BTW, the GNU `find` program is free software (so you should study its source code, e.g. of [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)...). And Linux has [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

Comment: You never update the `entry` variable

Comment: The `do { … } while` loop is completely inappropriate.  It should be `while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)`.

Comment: One aspect of your problem is described in [Why is `stat()` not working after `readdir()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168266/why-is-stat-not-working-after-readdir).  I'm tempted to close as a duplicate, but there are other issues here too.

Comment: I don't really agree with the closure as there is only one clear error that causes the subdirectories not being traversed, and it is obvious with bare sight. + that the `entry` is not reassigned as it should be. (it works because it has been statically allocated). The question includes a) desired behaviour, b) a specific problem, c) shortest code to reproduce, d) in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is in the while condition, you are abandoning the return value of `readdir`, it should be assigned to entry.

Also, when calling `listdir` recursively, you should prepend the parent name before the path, other wise it will always search from current working directory.
Try this version:

```
void listdir(const char *name) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int file_size;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
            return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {   // <--- setting entry
            printf("%s/%s\n", name, entry->d_name);
            if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
                    char path[1024];
                    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                            continue;
                    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);  // <--- update dir name properly by prepend the parent folder.
                    listdir(path);
            }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    listdir(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your early return leaks an open directory descriptor.  That's not good.  The `do { … } while` loop is wholly inappropriate — both in the question and in the answer.

Comment: Right, dir should be closed before return.The loop could be better also.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a minimal fix to your code. I took the liberty of using the non-standard `asprintf` here; if you're not using glibc, you should use `snprintf` or alike instead.

Most notably, the path given to `listdir` must be a complete relative path from the current working directory; or an absolute path. However the one in `entry->d_name` is just the basename of the file. Thus it has to be concatenated with the path passed in to the `listdir`. I've also changed the inappropriate `do`...`while` into a `while` loop here.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void listdir(const char *path) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(path)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        char *current;
        if (asprintf(&current, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name) < 0) {
            // asprintf failed
            fprintf(stderr, "asprintf failed, exiting");
            goto exit;
        }

        puts(current);
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            listdir(current);
        }

        free(current);
    }

exit:
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    listdir(".");
}
```